# Do the books make any reference to Flitwick being a duelling champion?

Tags: harry-potter

Fan fics, even those as early as 2006, make reference to Professor Flitwick being a duelling champion. I don't recall seeing this anywhere in the original seven books. Is the original source in those or does it come from elsewhere?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is mentioned by Hermione in Chamber of Secrets.

> The ceiling was velvety black once more and most of the school seemed
> to be packed beneath it, all carrying their wands and looking excited.
> “I wonder who’ll be teaching us?” said Hermione as they edged into the
> chattering crowd. “Someone told me Flitwick was a dueling champion
> when he was young — maybe it’ll be him.”
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets. Chapter Eleven. The Dueling Club.</sub>

Comment: Odd that she doesn't know for sure - you'd think Hermione would've looked it up. Unless the student dueling champion doesn't get into *Hogwarts: A History*.

Comment: @Cadence it was mentioned in Goblet of Fire that dueling is illegal, so it would probably not make it into the official histories. At least not while Flitwick's still around to demand satisfaction.

Comment: @HAEM Those are two different things, I think. Duelling, in the sense of throwing down the gauntlet and challenging someone to a fight to the death, is outlawed; but duelling as a sport to test skill is likely not outlawed. This would entirely in line with, arguably, the closest real-world equivalent to wand-fighting, namely fencing: fencing as a sport is legal, but duelling with swords is not.

Comment: @Cadence Not _that_ odd – she doesn’t seem particularly interested in sports in general. She only just musters an interest in Quidditch, despite most of her friends being active players. Simply hearing that Flitwick did duelling in his youth wouldn’t necessarily make her go seek out old records of historical duelling championships.